# ID Getting Lost In Loop

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, post, while-loop

I've been working on a way to build an archive for new threads. The over all goal was to make it so that if someone wanted to edit or delete a news thread they could, as well they could save a thread as a draft so that it ain't displayed to the public. I am using MySQL to store all the news threads, and I have it so that it prints out every news feed and the information for it. But when i click the edit button to edit that thread, it ALWAYS uses the id for the last MySQL entry called and NOT the ID I set it to use via a hidden form. Anyways here's the code and all parts to it. I'm so confused, and could really use some help. If you got questions just ask.

Main Script: http://pastebin.com/hn3cgVXu
Article_Post: http://pastebin.com/hhaLkuXe
Article_Archive: http://pastebin.com/X2fDg4dk

The original value for ID is called from the database, and set from article_archive

Display:
http://i25.photobucket.com/albums/c51/dog199200/Untitled-2.png

The Pencil is Edit, Trash Can is Delete. The image clearly shows that the loop is getting the ID, but that specific ID isn't being passed when the edit image is clicked.

Comment: You should be using mysql_real_escape_string instead of htmlentities - it's a huge security hole otherwise.

Comment: Please explain the difference and why in more detail.. I have been told so many different things on what to use by so many different people that it's confusing :-/

Comment: http://us3.php.net/mysql_real_escape_string - Because it's a function specifically designed for what you're trying to do :)

Comment: A ok makes a little more sense, but I should actually be using both.  htmlentities for each time I need to use the value, and mysql_real_escape_string when i'm storing the value back. That should cover all possible issues.

Comment: whichdan@ I am using mysql_real_escape_string now instead of htmlentities. But when I call the information back there is a lot of \'s. How do I remove them?

Comment: Do you have magic_quotes_gpc enabled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `Article_Archive` when you loop through your database results you are naming your hidden input field the same thing for all the results.

```
<?php 
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($news_list)) {
  echo "<form action=\"" . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . "\" method=\"post\" id=\"result_".$row['id']."\" name=\"result_".$row['id']."\">";
  // ...
  echo "... <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"id\" value=\"".$row['id']."\">";
  // ...
  echo "</form>";
} ?>
```

You're calling it `id`, so when you place multiple hidden input fields on the same form it will just grab the last one.  Where is the javascript for when you click `edit`? You won't be able to do a standard form submit with that code since you're overwriting all the input fields with the same `name` attribute.

Comment: I already realize that. I was trying to figure out a way to work around that, preferable without using javascript at all.

Comment: You could try changing the names to array keys, such as name="id[]" - would that work?

Comment: Where is the `submit` for the form?  You'll need to have multiple forms then. (edited my code)

Comment: My submit buttons are the last two input fields. And I followed your example above, but now how do i get it so that each is called separately, because just doing that alone isn't working

Comment: Nevermind, my FTP client didn't update the file. I got it working

Comment: Having the separate form tags with the submit buttons within them should submit each sets of inputs separately (updated my code adding a `name` tag to the form)